# How to substring a string?

Tags: python, regex, substring, jython

I have a string `"MenuItem {Open source}"`.

How can I get the string `Open source` from my string?

e.g.

```
str1 = "MenuItem {Open source}"
```

perform some actions to set string two to be...

```
print str2  # 'Open source'
```

How can I acheive this using python or jython?

Comment: Read the `re` module documentation. Read the documentation on strings, their methods, and slices. Read the documentation on `for` and `while` loops. Find and read a tutorial on Python. See a pattern?

Answer (score 10):

You can get it with a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

```
>>> import re
>>> str1 = "MenuItem {Open source}"
>>> re.search(r'{(.*)}', str1).group(1)
'Open source'
```

You can also get it by splitting the string on the `{` and `}` delimiters (here I use `str.rsplit` rather than `str.split` to make sure it splits at the right-most match):

```
>>> str1.rsplit('{')[1].rsplit('}')[0]
'Open source'
```

Answer (score 5):

Extracting substrings: Strings in Python can be subscripted just like an array: `s[4] = 'a'`. Like in IDL, indices can be specified with slice notation i.e., two indices separated by a colon. This will return a substring containing characters index1 through index2-1. Indices can also be negative, in which case they count from the right, i.e. -1 is the last character. Thus substrings can be extracted like

```
  s = "Go Gators! Come on Gators!"

  x = s[3:9] #x = "Gators"
  x = s[:2] #x = "Go"
  x = s[19:] #x = "Gators!"
  x = s[-7:-2] #x = "Gator"
```

Therefore in your examplel, you'll need `str2 = str1[10:21] = "Open Source"`.

Of course, that's assuming it's always Open Source and MenuItem...

Instead, you can use `find`:

```
int find(sub [,start[,end]])
```

returns the numeric position of the first occurance of sub in the string. Returns -1 if sub is not found.

```
  x = s.find("Gator") #x = 3
  x = s.find("gator") #x = -1
```

So you can use `str1.find("{")` to get the first brace, and `str1.find("}")` to get the second.

or in one:

```
str2 = str1[str1.find("{"):str1.find("}")]
```

untested code, you may need to add a +1 somewhere, but in theory that should work,  or at least get you on the right track ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var1 = "MenuItem {Open source}"
var2 = var1.find('{')
var3 = var1.find('}')
ans = var1[var2+1: var3]
print ans
```

There you are with the string "Open source"!!!